# CSS "inner border":hover on div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working in a bootstrap "rollover" effect. Currently I have a simple fluid grid with images inside:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 py-0 px-0 mx-0 my-0"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x150" class="img-fluid introImgRoll"></a></div>

<div class="col-md-6 py-0 px-0 mx-0 my-0" box><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x150" class="img-fluid introImgRoll"></a>
</div></div>

<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 py-0 px-0 mx-0 my-0"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x150" class="img-fluid introImgRoll"></a></div>

<div class="col-md-6 py-0 px-0 mx-0 my-0" box><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x150" class="img-fluid introImgRoll"></a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

and a simple css with introImgRoll class:

```
.introImgRoll:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border: 5px solid black;

}

.introImgRoll:hover img  {
    margin: -5px;
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

Please take a look at: [Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/kriszap/pen/Opgmjg) especially when you hover over blue boxes, because images need to be responsive (fluid class) border destroys entire structure. 
So I did some research and wanted to balance 5px border with -5px margin of the image. Unfortunately it seems to be not working.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: try `box-sizing: padding-box;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.introImgRoll` does not have `img` child -> it is the `img`. Change the last part of your CSS to:

```
.introImgRoll:hover {
    margin: -5px;
    box-sizing: content-box; /* will solve the problem. */
}
```

**Box-shadow Method:**

```
.row a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.row a:hover::before {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px black;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.row a:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: OMG you're right, there's no img child! To many hours trying to figure things out today... Still when I add your code it looks like that: http://codepen.io/kriszap/pen/XMggKm All I want is the "inside border" kind of thing, any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Use box-shadow then. Take a look at my edit. It's a bit tricky but it works.

Comment: Wow, that's tricky indeed, but it works! I experience 1px gap in the middle in Safari (between boxes) but in Chrome it works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Try applying `font-size: 0;` on the parent. the gap may be a font gap :)

Answer (score 1):

please try below code.

```
.introImgRoll:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border: 5px solid black;
     margin: -5px 0px;

}
```

```css
.introImgRoll:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
  border: 5px solid black;
   margin: -5px 0px;
}

.introImgRoll:hover img {
  margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 py-0 px-0 mx-0 my-0">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x150" class="img-fluid introImgRoll"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 py-0 px-0 mx-0 my-0" box>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x150" class="img-fluid introImgRoll"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 py-0 px-0 mx-0 my-0">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x150" class="img-fluid introImgRoll"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 py-0 px-0 mx-0 my-0" box>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x150" class="img-fluid introImgRoll"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

use `margin : -5px 0px;` when hover the image

Comment: Thx! It looks promising but the border is quite strange, any chances to make it just i.e. 3px "inside border"? Currently looks like this: http://codepen.io/kriszap/pen/LWLLej